# Cannot determine the place to put a progress bar between various layouts

Tags: android, drawerlayout, androiddesignsupport, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an activity in which I have used FrameLayout, DrawerLayout, RelativeLayout and CoordinatorLayout.
Now I want to add this horizontal progress bar:

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressToolbar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:indeterminateOnly="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            />
```

However, I don't know where to place this in my code so that it appears above the recycler view and below the toolbar??
My activity xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="7dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
                layout="@layout/pmp_toolbar" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/pmp_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/rignt_bottom_floating_action_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/pink"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/pink_pressed"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/FF4081"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/green_pressed"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
            fab:fab_title="By Price" />


        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/action_c"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/FF4081"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/green_pressed"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
            fab:fab_title="By Rating" />
    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any answer would be grateful as I've already wasted hell of time on this.

Comment: you can put at top right

Comment: @Rustam can you just point out where exactly? I've updated the question. I need it above recycler view

Comment: after your 1st  <FrameLayout create another <FrameLayout with fill_parent and put the <ProgressBar inside it. You can then position to were ever you want on screen. In theory that should work.

Comment: @Tasos an answer would b really helpful. btw how to get it "Wherever I want on the screen?" . For now, example I wnat it below toolbar and above recylcer view. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thats easy. in the framelayout add (android:layout_marginTop="whatever(dp)) (margin-left, margin-right). by the way you can also use match_parent for the width, height. well i dont answer because i use this method to place icons where ever i want to position on screen on top of oher layouts, but never tried it with a progress bar. should be the same. if it works let me know and ill put in answer

Comment: @Tasos unforunately it didn't worked for me. beacuse the progress bar is fixed on the screen and is not moving up or down with the recycler scroll

Comment: another possible way would be to create a custom toolbar  -- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XfDDfa3rv8  -- and then add (android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar") to the progressbar